# Proving a theorem on limits

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

I need to prove that:

If $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)}f(x,y)= 0 \text{ and } g(x,y)\leq k,$$ then:  $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)}f(x,y) g(x,y) =0.$$

My approach is like follow:

$$|f(x,y)g(x,y)-0|=|f(x,y)g(x,y)|=|f(x,y)||g(x,y)|\leq|f(x,y)|k\leq k\frac{\varepsilon }{k}=\varepsilon $$

I don't know how to formally finish the prove.

Comment: I guess you want to say $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)=0$ in the first equation.

Comment: @Paul Yes, sorry the mistake!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} f(x,y) = 0$$ is telling that for all $\varepsilon >0$ you can find $\delta >0$ such that $$|(x,y) - (a,b)| < \delta$$ implies $$|f(x,y) - 0| < \frac{\varepsilon}{k}.$$ Therefore for every $\varepsilon >0$ we can pick the same $\delta$ and have that $$|f(x,y)g(x,y) - 0| = |f(x,y)| |g(x,y)| \leq |f(x,y)| k < k \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{k} = \varepsilon,$$ as we wanted.

That's all that you needed.

Comment: But how do you known a priori that $|f(x,y) - 0| < \frac{\varepsilon}{k}$, you choose $\frac{\varepsilon}{k}$ from the beggining?

Comment: You choose. Really, there is no logical problem in assuming $< \varepsilon$ and for $|f(x,y)g(x,y)|$ you bound with $k \varepsilon $. Analysts choose things backwards to get a pretty end result, often confusing learners (I know I was).